# How to get the latest crawl date of an index in GSA?

Tags: google-search-appliance

In GSA, under Index > Diagnostics > Index Diagnostics, there is a section "More information about this page" and there is a field "Last Modified", how could I get this value from the XML output of the search results?

Answer (score 0):

Do you not see it if you add getfields=* as a query parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Latest crawl date of the document can be exported using "Export URLs" feature of GSA.
Please read [this](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/admin_console_help/status_export_urls.html) document for more information.